# How to include canvas under panorama page in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, blend

I have a panorama page with two panorama item and would like to include a canvas inside the second panorama item. So, when I do it, I get a overflow of the first panorama item in my canvas. As it should be made such that it takes around one and half page. So it should be like 2 and a half panorama page with two items a panorama item and a canvas item.

Comment: Please show what you've got. Don't just describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the margin values are zero. Sometimes, Expression Blend will add margins to a child control to fit into the ItemTemplate of the panorama control. Remember a Canvas doesnt act like other components, it's contents are mapped to the pixel.

Also, if you are looking to make an item 1.5 page widths, consider changing the panorama item's orientation to horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put another canvas under the grid in your second panorama item?